# Socket.io POST Requests from Socket.IO-Client-Swift

Tags: python, ios, linux, sockets, flask

I am running socket.io on an Apache server through Python Flask. We're integrating it into an iOS app (using the [Socket.IO-Client-Swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) library) and we're having a weird issue.

From the client side code in the app (written in Swift), I can view the actual connection log (client-side in XCode) and see the connection established from the client's IP and the requests being made. The client never receives the information back (or any information back; even when using a global event response handler) from the socket server.

I wrote a very simple test script in Javascript on an HTML page and sent requests that way and received the proper responses back. With that said, it seems to likely be an issue with iOS. I've found these articles (but none of them helped fix the problem):

https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/issues/95
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/359

My next thought is to extend the logging of socket.io to find out exact what data is being POSTed to the socket namespace. Is there a way to log exactly what data is coming into the server (bear in mind that the 'on' hook on the server side that I've set up is not getting any data; I've tried to log it from there but it doesn't appear to even get that far).

I found mod_dumpio for Linux to log all POST requests but I'm not sure how well it will play with multi-threading and a socket server.

Any ideas on how to get the exact data being posted so we can at least troubleshoot the syntax and make sure the data isn't being malformed when it's sent to the server?

Thanks!

### Update

When testing locally, we got it working (it was a setting in the Swift code where the namespace wasn't being declared properly). This works fine now on localhost but we are having the exact same issues when emitting to the Apache server.

We are not using mod_wsgi (as far as I know; I'm relatively new to mod_wsgi, apologies for any ignorance). We used to have a .wsgi file that called the main app script to run but we had to change that because mod_wsgi is not compatible with Flask SocketIO (as stated in the uWSGI Web Server section [here](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). The way I am running the script now is by using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to run the .py file as a daemon (using that specifically so it will autostart in the event of a server crash).

Locally, it worked great once we installed the eventlet module through pip. When I ran `pip freeze` on my virtual environment on the server, eventlet was installed. I uninstalled and reinstalled it just to see if that cleared anything up and that did nothing. No other Python modules that are on my local copy seem to be something that would affect this.

One other thing to keep in mind is that in the function that initializes the app, we change the port to port 80:

```
socketio.run(app,host='0.0.0.0',port=80)
```

because we have other API functions that run through a domain that is pointing to the server in this app. I'm not sure if that would affect anything but it doesn't seem to matter on the local version.

I'm at a dead end again and am trying to find anything that could help. Thanks for your assistance!

### Another Update

I'm not exactly sure what was happening yet but we went ahead and rewrote some of the code, making sure to pay extra special attention to the namespace declarations within each socket event `on` function. It's working fine now. As I get more details, I will post them here as I figure this will be something useful for other who have the same problem. This thread also has some really valuable information on how to go about debugging/logging these types of issues although we never actually fully figured out the answer to the original question.

Comment: As far as I know socket.io mechanism and how it works is completely incompatible with Apache/mod_wsgi. Can you clarify what exactly you are meaning when you say you are using an Apache server?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton It is not "completely" incompatible, but I agree it is not a great match. You can use Flask-SocketIO's long-polling mechanism as long as you have sticky sessions and more than one thread per server. The actual requirement is that the client needs to be able to send a GET and a POST request concurrently, and these need to be handled also concurrently by the same Python server process.

Comment: That could only work if using daemon mode of mod_wsgi and had a single process with many threads. Even then, a possible problem is that in daemon mode both way traffic is not possible. It requires that all request content be sent across before any response will be processed and sent back. So if it expects that it can read a bit of the request, send back a bit of response, read a bit of a request, send back a bit of a response, and so on, that will not work.

Comment: Only other alternative it to make sure using Apache worker or event MPM and set it up Apache with only one child worker process which had many threads. This will allow both way traffic if using mod_wsgi embedded mode.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton the way Socket.IO implements long-polling does not require partial reads or streaming. The request payloads are read and processed entirely by the server before a response is generated, so that should not be a problem. Even though long-polling is feasible, I have never seen a successful Apache/mod_wsgi set up that includes WebSocket proxying.

Comment: If you want to try and get to the bottom of it if still having issues, then suggest using the mod_wsgi mailing list. If can supply a small example and instructions of what browser have to use to test via the mailing list I can have a play with it.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have verified that Apache does get the POST requests. That should be your first test, if Apache does not log the POST requests coming from iOS, then you have a different kind of problem.

If you do get the POST requests, then you can add some custom code in the middleware used by Flask-SocketIO and print the request data forwarded by Apache's mod_wsgi. The this is in file [flask_socketio/**init**.py](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/flask_socketio/__init__.py#L35-L38). The relevant portion is this:

```
class _SocketIOMiddleware(socketio.Middleware):

    # ...

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        # log what you need from environ here
        environ['flask.app'] = self.flask_app
        return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
```

You can find out what's in `environ` in the [WSGI specification](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/). In particular, the body of the request is available in `environ['wsgi.input']`, which is a file-like object you read from.

Keep in mind that once you read the payload, this file will be consumed, so the WSGI server will not be able to read from it again. Seeking the file back to the position it was before the read may work on some WSGI implementations. A safer hack I've seen people do to avoid this problem is to read the whole payload into a buffer, then replace `environ['wsgi.input']` with a brand new `StringIO` or `BytesIO` object.

Comment: Thanks Miguel!

A post request does happen. More details is that the socket connection happens because I do get a successfully 'connection' response but I don't actually get the emitted response from the 'on' connect function I have. It connects to the server, and when I try to emit from the client, I can see it pop up in the log (I'm using the tail command on the log to watch it) but then it just hangs and never receives a response. I've tried to find the POST logs in Apache but mod_dumpio doesn't seem to have anything in it.

Comment: My guess is that your set up is incompatible with Apache, but I can't really tell for sure. Please add details about the additional information to your question. It's really hard to understand your description because you are using vague terms such as "socket connection" (is it an HTTP connection over OS-level sockets, or do you mean WebSocket?), "log" (server-side or client-side log? Apache/mod_wsgi log? Flask-SocketIO log? syslog?) or "server" (Apache or Flask-SocketIO?). Please add snippets of the logs that demonstrate the parts that are working, and exact details of what you did so far.

Comment: Hi @Miguel, I've updated the post to have some more details of other approaches I've taken. I'm relatively new to mod_wsgi but I believe I have successfully disabled that since it isn't compatible with Flask SocketIO. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @MillerMedia still insufficient info. Post the Apache config that you are using. It's odd that you have the Flask server on port 80. What port do you have Apache on?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using flask-socketio on the server side? If you are, there is a lot of debugging available in the constructor.

socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

Comment: Any details on how to do that? I've been trying several different debugging methods.

Comment: Added constructor flags for debugging.